# Filter div by multiple condition in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two filtering section place and attraction i select a place show the place wise div and select attraction only filter with attraction wise, my filter code like

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu option-set" id="myBtnContainer" data-filter-group="type">
    <li class="selected active filter_btn" value>--Select city---</li>
    <li class="filter_btn" value="All">All</li>
    <li class="filter_btn" value="Trivan">Trivan</li>
    <li class="filter_btn" value="Quli">Quli</li>
</ul>

<ul class="dropdown-menu option-set2" id="myBtnContainer" data-filter-group="type">
    <li class="selected active filter_btn" value>--Select Attraction---</li>
    <li class="filter_btn" value="All">All</li>
    <li class="filter_btn" value="Musium">Musium</li>
    <li class="filter_btn" value="beach">beach</li>
</ul>
```

and div code like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="filterDiv Trivan Musium col-lg-4 col-12">
    <div class="filter_wrapper_div">
        <span class="filter_lg_head">tittle</span>
        <img src=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="filterDiv Quli Musium col-lg-4 col-12">
    <div class="filter_wrapper_div">
        <span class="filter_lg_head">tittle</span>
        <img src=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="filterDiv Quli beach col-lg-4 col-12">
    <div class="filter_wrapper_div">
        <span class="filter_lg_head">tittle</span>
        <img src=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

andjquery

```
    $('.option-set').change(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
        $('.filterDiv').removeClass('active');
        
        $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat')
            .filter('[class="' + input + '"]')
            .addClass('active');
        
        filterActive = input;
});

$('.option-set2').change(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
        $('.filterDiv').removeClass('active');
        
        $('.filter-cat-results .f-cat')
            .filter('[class="' + input + '"]')
            .addClass('active');
        
        filterActive = input;
});
```

Here i pass filter element in class  how we filter with two condition please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's not clear what you want to achieve, and what code you already have to do this (you mentioned jquery but didn't provide any jquery code at all).

Comment: Why do you use `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of `<select>` and `<option>`?

Comment: @Pipetus ok, i wand filter both conditions

Comment: @InSync thats is template design part

Comment: You have to work with select option tags instead of ul & li's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same function to handle both changes. Check if "All" is selected to filter accordingly.

```
$('.option-set, .option-set2').change(function() {
    var cityFilter = $('.option-set').val();
    var attractionFilter = $('.option-set2').val();
    
    $('.filterDiv').removeClass('active');
    
    if (cityFilter === 'All' && attractionFilter === 'All') {
        $('.filterDiv').addClass('active');
    } else if (cityFilter === 'All') {
        $('.filterDiv.' + attractionFilter).addClass('active');
    } else if (attractionFilter === 'All') {
        $('.filterDiv.' + cityFilter).addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.filterDiv.' + cityFilter + '.' + attractionFilter).addClass('active');
    }
});
```